# Organize a JSON array into a menu

Tags: arrays, json, string, bash, menu

I have this data from an API:

```json
[{"name":"***.com","id":"***-0a5864441f49","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.de","id":"***-0a5864441f49","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.com","id":"***-0a5864440f67","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.de","id":"***-0a5864441314","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.com","id":"***-0a586444968b","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.de","id":"***-0a5864441314","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.de","id":"***-0a5864441f49","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.de","id":"***-0a5864441f49","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.de","id":"***-0a58644406ac","type":"NATIVE"},{"name":"***.de","id":"***-0a58644435f4","type":"NATIVE"}]
```

and I want to create a menu from it looking like this:

```
Choose one:
1. ***.com ***-0a5864441f49
2. ***.de ***-0a5864441f49
and so on...
```

And I would like to then use the input further. What is the most efficient method to do this in bash?

I'm thinking of an array but I think IFS would not like me using `},{` as a delimiter, right?

I tried using IFS but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jq to transform the input to look something like this (see [playground](https://jqplay.org/s/5DSqTnRtHOo)):

```bash
$ jq -r 'map("\(.name) \(.id)")[]' infile.json
***.com ***-0a5864441f49
***.de ***-0a5864441f49
***.com ***-0a5864440f67
***.de ***-0a5864441314
-->8--
```

Based on that, you could read this output into an array, and then use the `select` built-in to present a menu:

```bash
readarray -t opts < <(jq -r 'map("\(.name) \(.id)")[]' infile.json)

PS3='Choose one: '
select opt in "${opts[@]}"; do
    echo "Do something with $opt"
    break
done
```

resulting in a prompt like

```
1) ***.com ***-0a5864441f49    6) ***.de ***-0a5864441314
2) ***.de ***-0a5864441f49     7) ***.de ***-0a5864441f49
3) ***.com ***-0a5864440f67    8) ***.de ***-0a5864441f49
4) ***.de ***-0a5864441314     9) ***.de ***-0a58644406ac
5) ***.com ***-0a586444968b   10) ***.de ***-0a58644435f4
Choose one:
```